# Getting multiple values out of a database using html/php multiple selector

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to extract multiple values from a row in a table in a mysql database. I want the selector to show the description only, and after the form is submitted, I want to be able to access additional information from that row. I am able to get all of the item_types out into an array, but I am not sure how to add the item_id. I don't want item_id to show up in the html selector.

I tried a few things like array_push. The only way I can think of getting this done is by making one big string in "value" and extracting the parts after the form is submitted.

Here is the function so far:

```
function createDropdown() {
    echo '<select multiple name="items[]">';
        try {
            $items = mysql_query("SELECT item_id,item_type FROM items");
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($items)) {
                echo '<option value="'.$row['item_type'].'"';
                echo '>'. $row['item_type'] . '</option>'."\n";
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'No results';
        }
echo '</select>';
}
```

Comment: You're mixing MySQL APIs and they do **not** mix. `mysql_query` + `catch(PDOException $e)` = no love. Something tells me you're probably using PDO connection, but hard to say when not seeing full code. However, that `PDOException` is not compatible with `mysql_`.

Comment: I am using mysql_connect to connect to the database, and $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] for the form action.

Comment: "One big string in 'value' and extracting" after submitted is one option, or you can write a bunch of hidden form inputs, and not have to extract. Please show an example of all the information you want to pass along with the form submission so we can recommend ways to accomplish that.

Comment: Unless i have misunderstood, you want the item_id to be returned for each 'item_type' selected. then just set the 'option value' to be the [item_id]'. The 'option value' is what i returned not what is seen. What is seen is the text between the ending '>item_text shown</option>. i.e. do: '<option value="'.$row['item_id'].'"'

Answer (score 0):

Hmm you can try to generate a lookup table whenever you create a drop-down list:

```
function createDropdown(&$ddlLookup) {
    echo '<select multiple name="items[]">';
        try {
            $items = mysql_query("SELECT item_id,item_type FROM items");
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($items)) {
                echo '<option value="'.$row['item_type'].'"';
                echo '>'. $row['item_type'] . '</option>'."\n";
                $ddlLookup[$item_type] = $item_id;
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'No results';
        }
echo '</select>';
}
```

Then whenever you need the id for a given description you use that table(array) to get it:

```
$mainDropdownLUT = array();
createDropdown($mainDropdownLUT);

var_dump($mainDropdownLUT['testCow']);
 -> 734
```

Also, if you need to pass it to another page it can be serialized and added to a hidden field.

```
 $mainDropdownLUT = serialize($mainDropdownLUT);
   "<input type="hidden" value =\"$mainDropdownLUT\">"
   -------------------------**OTHER PAGE **--------------
    $mainDropdownLUT = unserialize($mainDropdownLUT);
```